# Html.DropDownFor: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Updated:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m = item.SelectedType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownLoadRecoveryType, new { @class = "form-control"
```

Why am I getting this error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   express

I have scan all the questions here before posting and I'm stuck and I need help please.

here is my model:

```
public string SelectedType { get; set; }
```

here is my controller:

```
public static class RecoveryTypesDropDown
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RecoveryTypes { get; set; }
}

public void DropDownLoadRecoveryType()
{
   using (var context = new salt_entities())
   {
      var list = context.Types.OrderBy(b => b.Sort).ToList().Select(e => new { e.ID, e.Type });
      IEnumerable<SelectListItem> lists = list.Select(b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.ID.ToString().Trim(), Text = b.Type.Trim() }).ToList();
      RecoveryTypesDropDown.RecoveryTypes = lists;
    }
}

public ViewResult Collection(Guid id)
{
   ViewBag.DropDownLoadRecoveryType = RecoveryTypesDropDown.RecoveryTypes;
   //....
   foreach (var item in collectionViewModelList)
   {
     //....

     collectionViewModel.SelectedType = item.Type.Value;

   }

}
```

here is my .html razor code:

```
  @model IEnumerable<myapp.Models.CollectionViewModel>

  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
     @Html.DropDownList(item.SelectedType.Trim(), (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownLoadRecoveryType, new { @class = "form-control" })
  }
```

Comment: Remove `.Trim()` from `@Html.DropDownList(item.SelectedType.Trim(), ...`, but none of this will bind when you post back anyway (duplicate `name` attributes), and you generating invalid html with the duplicate `id` attributes

Comment: I did tried without Trim() as well but not diff and the reason I have added is the trim() thinking that maybe I'm getting some whitespace but again removed and does not make any diff

Comment: what duplicate `name attributes` you talking about?

Comment: Check the html your generating - all the dropdowns have `name="SelectedType"` and `id="SelectedType"` (nothing will be bound to your model when you post back). And why on earth do you have a static property for `RecoveryTypes`?

Comment: If removing `.Trim()` did not work then you must have other html helpers where you are using `Trim()` or some other method on the property value.

Comment: the reason I'm using static class/prop so that I do not have to instantiate (there is a reason why I'm using) but I do not think that by using the static is causing the problem, but what exactly causing the problem and I have used many times DropDownListFor in so many other pages but this is driving me crazy...

Comment: The static class and property are not necessary ,is bad practice and is not thread safe. You can simplify all this by just assigning the `SelectList` to the `ViewBag` property (or preferably to a view model property) `ViewBag.DropDownLoadRecoveryType = new SelectList(context.Types.OrderBy(b => b.Sort), "ID", "Type");`

Comment: I have tried it but did not work... if you able to make it work on your local machine will you be able to show the code?

Comment: I suggest you open a view that's working. Then change one of the helpers (say for a textbox) that relates to a string property and add `.Trim()`  - e.g. `@TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty.Trim())` and run it again. You will see the identical error. If removing `.Trim()` did not work for the dropdown, its because you also have other errors on the page.

Comment: I do not know why you go hung on Trim() and it has nothing to do with the error I have posted above... anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: Calling a method on a property inside a helper has **everything** to do with it.

Comment: will you post some code so I can follow you or have better understanding what exactly you referring?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72192/discussion-between-abu-hamzah-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial problem is use of `.Trim()` in the html helper. As the message states, the helper needs to access a property, but the use of `.Trim()` means it accessing a method on the property (not the property itself), hence the exception.

In addition you should not be using static properties (not thread safe). But the main problem you have is that your not constructing your html properly and generating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and `name` attributes by using a `foreach` loop so binding will fail. Instead use a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `CollectionViewModel`

View/Shared/EditorTemplates/CollectionViewModel.cshtml

```
@model CollectionViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedType, (SelectList)ViewData["RecoveryTypes"], new { @class = "form-control" })
// other controls for properties of CollectionViewModel
```

and in the main view

```
@model IEnumerable<CollectionViewModel>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { RecoveryTypes = ViewBag.RecoveryTypes })
  <input type="submit" /> 
}
```

In the controller

```
public ViewResult Collection(Guid id)
{
  var list = context.Types.OrderBy(b => b.Sort);
  ViewBag.RecoveryTypes = new SelectList(list, "ID", "Type");
  IEnumerable<CollectionViewModel> model = ??
  ....
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Collection(IEnumerable<CollectionViewModel> model)
{
  // save and redirect
}
```

Note the html will now include indexers so the collection can be bound when you post back

```
<select name="[0].SelectedItem" ....>
<select name="[1].SelectedItem" ....>
```

If the value of property `SelectItem` matches the value of one of the options your generating, then that item will be selected when you first render the page.